# How to intercept and modify SQL of PreparedStatement with Spring?

Tags: prepared-statement, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Is there a central location in the JDBCTemplate (or related) where SQL manipulations can be performed immediately before they are sent to the DB?

I want to prepend a comment-line to each and every SQL statement that gets issued to the RDBMS.

Hope there is a dedicated extension point. Otherwise, I would need to write my own class that inherits from JDBCTemplate and adds my custom logic, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Something like this https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-statementinspector/ would be great, however, this uses Hibernate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a central location in the `JDBCTemplate` (or related) where `SQL` manipulations can be performed immediately before they are sent to the DB?

Yes, the [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html).

With [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) you can intercept queries on `DataSource` level using a custom [`QueryTransformer`](https://ttddyy.github.io/datasource-proxy/docs/current/api/net/ttddyy/dsproxy/transform/QueryTransformer.html):

```java
private static class MyQueryTransformer implements QueryTransformer {
  @Override
  public String transformQuery(TransformInfo transformInfo) {
    String query = transformInfo.getQuery();
    // transform query
    return query;
  }
}
```

and supplying it into `ProxyDataSourceBuilder`:

```java
ProxyDataSourceBuilder.create()
    ...
    .queryTransformer(new MyQueryTransformer())
    ...
```

See also [datasource-proxy-examples](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy-examples/)